# NOT VALID! Unittest is not run when it has a decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators, python-unittest

**EDIT: As I've answered below this question is not valid since it was all a misunderstanding on my behalf.**

I have made a try-except decorator for custom errors and I want to apply this decorator on my unit tests. However, when that is done and there is a `raise SomeError` statement within the decorated unit tests scope (a function called from the test case will throw a `SomeError` if some certain test requirements aren't met), and this Error Class is caught in my decorator, then the test is never executed. However if i remove any raise `SomeError` statements within the testcase, it runs fine.

My decorator:

```
def try_exceptor(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(self):
        try:
            return f(self)
        except KeyError as k:
            print k
        except MyLocustFailError as mlfe:
            print mlfe.message
            newer_assert(mlfe.load_test, mlfe.response, mlfe.message)
    return inner
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this? What do you want to happen when the test throws a `KeyError`? Are you trying to rewrite [`unittest.TestCase.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) yourself?

Comment: The KeyError was just added for trouble shooting the behavior described in my question. I'm combining the test source (test case function(s)) to be used with both Python unittest and the Locust load testing module. The decorator would allow me to move the try-except statement from each single test case into one decorator.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Why are you using a try-except in a test case? Can it really be correct for the same code to either throw an exception, or not throw an exception? Maybe you need to give a slightly more specific example? How does `assertRaises()` not give you the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: The Locust load testing module have it's own way of setting a test case failure (must also say that I'm no Locust expert so this solution is what I have come up with as of now). Hence if I want to set a fail status during a  Locust run and terminate execution, I throw my custom error. It should also be said that the execution is always either as a unittest (using the unittest module) or as a Locust test. If there were no Locust module involved I would never have this approach with the decorator and tr-except..

Comment: Dan Getz, thanks for your input, but as you can see in my answer, the problem was a misunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit embarrassed but I must confess that there never was an issue as I described in my question. Just realized that due to my bad logging setup, the output partially went to my log file (facepalm) for certain scenarios. And because of a changed parameter in a function signature which I did not handle in the function body, the unittest was never asserted as a failure when it should have been. Fooling me to believe that there was something wrong with my decorator.